# Combining multiple rows into one using group by in t/sql

Tags: t-sql, group-by

I need to combine 2 rows like this:

```
Name     Option
John     Priority
John     Insurance
```

... into one like this:

```
Name     Option
John     Both
```

If there was only one row for John in the source table, then the result's Option value should be the same as in the table.

With Group By, I am not sure what goes in here:

```
 select Name, case when Count(Option) > 1 then 'Both' else ??? end Option
 group by Name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's only one row/value then Max() will give you that value. so you could try:

```
select Name, case when Count(Option) > 1 then 'Both' else Max(Option) end as Option
from whatever
group by Name
```

This will only really make sense if you can be sure there will only ever be two options.